# My bootable USB Device does not show up in the Boot Order Menu in BIOS when I am in UEFI Mode but it does in Legacy

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi

I was even able to Install Ubuntu in Legacy Mode but thats not really what I want to do. I tried basically any Option I could find regarding this Problem, but I couldnt find a solution yet.

my Laptop is the Acer Travelmate x349 g2 
i used rufus to create the bootable usb 
and i want to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Rather than using `rufus` try using `mkusb`: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073

Comment: You may have to turn on allow UEFI boot. And system needs UEFI on, but maybe not UEFI Secure boot. But once installed you will need UEFI Secure Boot to set password and enable "trust" to boot ubuntu/grub. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Comment: unfortunately that didnt help at all, the USB Drive still wont show up... its so frustrating.

Comment: @oldfred I answered before I saw your comment, I will try that as well, thanks!

Comment: It finally worked! Thanks so much, great step by step tutorial that you linked, not sure why I didn't find it before.

Comment: @deeliciouscode post the way you solved the problem please so that others can benefit